# How to add two foreign keys in message table of same(user) table as foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to design a chatting app using Django rest at the backend

My Model

```
class MessageModel(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    msg_from = models.ForeignKey(UserModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    msg_to = models.ForeignKey(UserModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but it gives the following error

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
message_api.MessageModel.msg_from: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'message_api.MessageModel.msg_from' clashes with reverse accessor for 'message_api.MessageModel.msg_to'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'message_api.MessageModel.msg_from' or 'message_api.MessageModel.msg_to'.
message_api.MessageModel.msg_to: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'message_api.MessageModel.msg_to' clashes with reverse accessor for 'message_api.MessageModel.msg_from'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'message_api.MessageModel.msg_to' or 'message_api.MessageModel.msg_from'.
```

How can I design a database table for chatting?
I am using MySQL database.

Comment: Set `related_name` to `'messages_sent'` and `'messages_received'` respectively. Do *not* use a `Model` suffix.

Comment: I am new to Django rest can you please give me the code..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MessageModel(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    msg_from = models.ForeignKey(UserModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="msg_sender")
    msg_to = models.ForeignKey(UserModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="msg_reciever")
```

> Good advice from Willem also don't use the `Model` suffix, instead name your models "Message" and "User"

Comment: Thank you for advice but Model suffix help me to differentiate between Models and Serializer classes.

Comment: @Amol_G: you should use a `Serializer` as suffix for serializers, but not a `Model` suffix for models.

Comment: Ok thanks, there is any specific reason to do not to use Model as a suffix?

Comment: @Amol_G: because the object is a `Message`, not a `MessageModel`. It will also set as `verbose_name = 'message model' instead of `message` and `message models` instead of `messages` as `verbose_name_plural`.